What is the config file that determines colors for the save dialog box?
I'm running Kubuntu. The theme is Edna.
I know I've changed something somewhere, but my save dialog box looks like this:

The icons for up, views, sorting, etc are all grey and almost match the background, and I can't work out where to change them. I have the same issue with a few other dialog boxes, but there's no obvious place to change them.
All help is appreciated.

Is this any use? https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dark_mode_switching#KDE

That seems like a problem with the color scheme you're using, try another one.
